# How do I add my list to my class?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following class but I cannot get my list to populate. I am not getting any errors or even null pointer exceptions. It just runs through and give me all of my data except my list. Could someone help me understand what I did wrong?

```js
import java.util.List;

public class SSRSReports {

  public static class Report {

    private String reportName;
    private String lastRunTime;
    private String lastStatus;
    private String deliveryExt;
    private String path;
    private String subscriptionId;
    private String jobId;
    private List < ReportSchedule > schedule;

    public Report(String reportName, String lastRunTime, String lastStatus, String deliveryExt, String path, String subscriptionId, String jobId, List < ReportSchedule > schedule) {
      this.setReportName(reportName);
      this.setLastRunTime(lastRunTime);
      this.setLastStatus(lastStatus);
      this.setDeliveryExt(deliveryExt);
      this.setPath(path);
      this.setSubscriptionId(subscriptionId);
      this.setJobId(jobId);
      this.setSchedule(schedule);
    }

    //Getters and Setters
    public List < ReportSchedule > getSchedule() {
      return schedule;
    }

    public void setSchedule(List < ReportSchedule > schedule) {
        this.schedule = schedule;
      }
      //The rest of Getters and Setters

  }

  public static class ReportSchedule {

    private String location;
    private String status;
    private String path;
    private String fileName;
    private String format;
    private String writeMode;
    private String site;

    public ReportSchedule(String location, String status, String path, String fileName, String format, String writeMode, String site) {

      this.setLocation(location);
      this.setStatus(status);
      this.setPath(path);
      this.setFileName(fileName);
      this.setFormat(format);
      this.setWriteMode(writeMode);
      this.setSite(site);
    }

    //Getters and Setters

  }



}
```

Here are the objects and the methods that I am using to populate them.

```js
List < Report > scheduledReports = new ArrayList < Report > ();
List < ReportSchedule > reportSchedule = new ArrayList < ReportSchedule > ();

//Do stuff to get data

reportSchedule.add(new ReportSchedule(location, status, subPath, fileName, format, writeMode, site));

scheduledReports.add(new Report(reportName, lastRunTime, lastStatus, deliveryExt, path, subscriptionId, jobId, reportSchedule));
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you actually trying to populate your list? And how are you verifying its absence?

Comment: I think you forgot to set schedule variable,
after you populate your list:
`schedule = scheduleReports;`
or if its outside this class:
`setSchedule(scheduledReports)`

Comment: Unrelated, but a list of things should be named as a plural, not a singular. (Unless you call it singularThingList, which I personally don't care for.)

Comment: I verified it's absence by printing the string after I converted it to a JSON object and noticed that it wasn't there. I figured it would. I was actually trying to populate it when I call my scheduledReports.add and just add the reportSchedule in with the new object. It sounds like I am missing something. Could you also elaborate on what you mean by setSchedule? Where do I place that?

Comment: So I tried adding the following to my script 

scheduledReports.add(new Report(reportName,lastRunTime,lastStatus,deliveryExt,path,subscriptionId,jobId,Report.setSchedule(reportSchedule)));

but now it  says  "java Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setSchedule"  

If I chance setSchedule to a public static the this.schedule cannot be used.

Comment: scheduledReports.add(new Report(reportName,lastRunTime,lastStatus,deliveryExt,path,subscriptionId,jobId,sch.setSchedule(reportSchedule))); But no values are being imported into my reportSchedule. I'm going to check that object and let you know what I find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it. I forget I had another result set being referenced which was preventing data from going into the list but, I also needed to do what Msumera suggested. I needed to set the object.

```js
Report sch = new Report(jobId, jobId, jobId, jobId, jobId, jobId, jobId, reportSchedule);

scheduledReports.add(new Report(reportName, lastRunTime, lastStatus, deliveryExt, path, subscriptionId, jobId, sch.setSchedule(reportSchedule)));
```